# Is there a way to authorize Microsoft API with MFA enabled using Playwright, TypeScript, and Axios without using a graphical user interface?

Tags: typescript, api, axios, automation, playwright

I need to authorize an API using Microsoft login, which will later redirect to a URI in my web application. Is there a way to authorize Microsoft without using a graphical user interface (UI)? The account I'm using has MFA (Multi-Factor Authentication) enabled, and I'm able to generate the MFA code within my code. I'm attempting to automate APIs using Playwright (TypeScript).

async  getAuthorizationCode() {
const loginResponse = await axios.post(authURL, {
client_id: clientId,
redirect_uri: callbackURL,
response_type: 'code',
username,
password,
});

```
    // Extract the authorization code from the login response
    const authorizationCode = loginResponse.headers['authorization-code'];
    mfaCode = this.fillCodeField();
    // Complete the MFA verification
    await axios.post(accessTokenURL, {
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      client_id: clientId,
      redirect_uri: callbackURL,
      code: authorizationCode,
      mfa_code: mfaCode,
    });
  
    return authorizationCode;
  }
  
  async  getAccessToken(authorizationCode) {
    const response = await axios.post(accessTokenURL, {
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      client_id: clientId,
      redirect_uri: callbackURL,
      code: authorizationCode,
    });
  
    return response.data.access_token;
  }
```

Comment: Hey Automated test, when you state: "I'm attempting to automate APIs using Playwright (TypeScript)." I think you might be using the wrong tool for the job. You should be able to do automated testing of API's using an existing TypeScript API testing framework, example project: https://github.com/codewithmmak/api-testing-protractor-typescript. Authorization of API's should be possible without browser based actions.